# How do I add a tag slug to a category URL to filter posts?

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, urls, tags, slug

I want to add an option to my site to filter posts by one specific tag on the category page and at the same time have a nice URL (no query strings).

So something like this:

`https://example.com/%category%/` - standard category link (currently)

`https://example.com/%category%/%tag%/` - a page like the above, but displaying posts from a specific category AND tag.

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

---

I would also like to note that for posts I have such a slug `https://example.com/%category%/%postname%/`  and I'm worried that there might be a conflict with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution.

By default in WP there is an option to filter categories by tags. E.g. `https://example.com/category_name?tag=tag_name`. I added a rewrite rule and redirection:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/

```php
add_action( 'init', function () {
    add_rewrite_rule( '([a-z0-9-]+)\/tag\/([a-z0-9-]+)\/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&tag=$matches[2]', 'top' );
} );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', function () {
    if ( is_category() && is_tag() && ! empty( $_GET['tag'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_category_link( get_the_category()[0] ) . 'tag/' . get_query_var( 'tag' ) . '/' );
        exit();
    }
} );
```

Of course it's just such a basic code. It will require additional adjustments, e.g. for SEO.